# Which would be faster in Crystal, a Hash or a case expression for lookups?

Tags: crystal-lang

Which would be faster in looking up a String against a known group, a Hash(String=>Bool) or a `case`?

```
input = %w(a b c x y z)
valid = { "a" => true, "z" => true }
input.find { |x|

  !valid.has_key?(x)

  # or

  case x
  when "a", "z"
    false
  else
    true
  end
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a small amount of relatively small comparison values known at compile time, it is certainly the fastest and (as Faustino pointed out) most memory-efficient to employ direct comparisons.

The `case` and `NamedTuple` examples essentially boil down to a series of `x == "a" || x == "z"`. This is as simple as it gets, meaning a very low code complexity, no heap allocations, fast comparison.

When using a hash, each comparison invokes the hashing algorithm (hence the name) which adds quite a bit of overhead. Hashes are however a great data structure for storing complex values or dynamic values not known at compile time.

When comparing larger collections of strings, at some point the simplistic approach is not that efficient anymore because it needs to compare each and every item in full length. A more efficient approach are specialized data structures for this kind of lookup known as prefix tree (see https://github.com/luislavena/radix for a Crystal implementation).

Answer (score 5):

crystal doesn't have `.detect` but `.find` method. (see [Why](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/wiki/FAQ#why-are-aliases-discouraged))

`Hash` is allocating heap memory so, is slower than `case` statement.

Also you can try using an immutable structure like `NameTupple`, very close to `case` performance

```
     hash  46.48M ( 21.51ns) (±14.08%)  3.90× slower
nametuple 173.82M (  5.75ns) (±15.75%)  1.04× slower
     case 181.28M (  5.52ns) (±13.24%)       fastest
```

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org), 450 bytes

```ruby
require "benchmark"

input = %w(a b c x y z)
valid1 = {"a" => true, "z" => true}
valid2 = {"a": true, "z": true}

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("hash") do
    input.find do |x|
      !valid1.has_key?(x)
    end
  end
  x.report("nametuple") do
    input.find do |x|
      !valid2.has_key?(x)
    end
  end
  x.report("case") do
    input.find do |x|
      case x
      when "a", "z"
        false
      else
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBda4MwFH3PrzgLDBSmsD4WusH@SIl6rdI0uiS2sev@@lyaxrlHAzfc88G5l1vq0Vghp0nT59BqAi9Ilc1J6CNnrFX9YLHD8yURKFDCYcQ1ZWch2@rVC19ccOzeYPVAL@DXP/D98GyiZ7s4tlFnH/OgvO0Nqg43d2OAyzX1nbYJb4RpeOoVzwJhl7xuVbV47@/psUzu3fsjje@JS4NCqmLzv2QqcSI79JLWBm9WBpfCrMi8u@AiuDSk4I8TzhI5oBbSUES0tAhnm/kw/P8qvqbpp6ylOJgpy1SXVVQMB99qkuSn/gI)

Comment: This is a very good answer. Just a tiny nitpick: Once I fill up the NamedTuple with  more values, there seems to be a drastic drop  in performance  (45× slower, --release --no-debug) compared to the CASE expression: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/3196 (I tried using tio.run but the URL is too long and SO won't allow URL shorteners.)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, `case` is the fastest by far https://carc.in/#/r/31y6 (copy the tio.run url)